Old index.html still appears after migration from webpack to Vite
I had a React application deployed on Kubernetes cluster - built using webpack + babel, deployed using express in Docker container. Now I have migrated it to Vite + nginx in pods for serving static content instead. Cluster is opened via nginx ingress controller. When I try to reach the site it still server me the old index.html with wrong configuration which results in this error in the console:
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'

since one of the js files server HTML code. How to avoid such deprecated version of HTMl to appear?
This is the Vite config file:
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react';
import tsConfigpaths from 'vite-tsconfig-paths';

export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react(), tsConfigpaths()],
  build: {
    outDir: 'dist',
    commonjsOptions: { transformMixedEsModules: true },
    rollupOptions: {
      output: {
        assetFileNames: 'assets/[name].[hash].[ext]',
        chunkFileNames: 'assets/[name].[hash].js',
        entryFileNames: 'assets/[name].[hash].js',
      },
    },
  },
});

